# combining multiple workbooks into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to get data recorded into excel workbooks to be automatically copied over onto one "mass data" sheet. The files are named by date ex. "5-28-17". There is one for each day of the month. I'd like to collect all data into one sheet, as previously stated, in order by date descending. 
I am currently using this code which should place all of the different workbooks onto their own worksheet, but I am having issues with that as well.

```
 Option Explicit
Const path As String = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
Sub GetSheets()
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet

FileName = Dir(path & "*.xls*")
Do While FileName <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
For Each sheet In wb.Sheets
    sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next sheet
wb.Close
FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

I am trying to do this with VBA. There are 15 columns in the sheets I'm pulling from and the sheet I want to copy to. All line up perfectly. Is there a way to move the sheets from the WB I'm currently working on which should contain a worksheet for each WB onto one mass worksheet? Or can I pull all data directly from the folder with all of the workbooks saved by date to one worksheet?

Comment: thank you I did not know this existed

Comment: the code runs, but there is no output. any idea why?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1184-excel-merge-multiple-worksheets-into-one.html Check out this as it has more comments may help you to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this AddIn.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

It will do what you want, and a whole lot more as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an MS Access database. Not to worry if you do not have the Office GUI .exe app installed. Because you use a Windows machine, you do have its Jet/ACE SQL Engine (.dll files).

**CREATE DATABASE**

```
Sub CreateDatabase()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim fso As Object, olDb As Object, db As Object
    Const dbLangGeneral = ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0"    
    Const strpath As String = "C:\Path\To\ExcelDatabase.accdb"

    ' CREATE DATABASE
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set olDb = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")

    If Not fso.FileExists(strpath) Then
        Set db = olDb.CreateDatabase(strpath, dbLangGeneral)
    End If

    MsgBox "Successfully created database!", vbInformation

ExitSub:
    Set db = Nothing: Set olDb = Nothing: Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

**CREATE, POPULATE, EXPORT EXCEL TABLE** *(Excel files never opened)*

```
Sub CreateTable()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim constr As String, FileName As String, i As Integer
    Const xlpath As String = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
    Const accpath As String = "C:\Path\To\ExcelDatabase.accdb"

    ' CONNECT TO DATABASE
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accpath & ";"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open constr

    i = 1
    FileName = Dir(xlpath & "*.xls*")  

    Do While FileName <> ""
        If i = 1 Then
            ' CREATE TABLE VIA MAKE TABLE QUERY
            conn.Execute "SELECT * INTO MyExcelTable" _ 
                          & " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;" _
                          & " Database=" & xlpath & FileName & "].[Sheet1$]"
        Else 
            ' POPULATE VIA APPEND QUERY
            conn.Execute "INSERT INTO MyExcelTable" _ 
                          & " SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;" _
                          & " Database=" & xlpath & FileName & "].[Sheet1$]"
        End If

        i = i + 1
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

   ' EXPORT TO EXCEL
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM MyExcelTable", conn

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MASS_DATA").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

    ' CLOSE CONNECTION
    rst.Close: conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully created and populated table!", vbInformation

ExitSub:
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitSub    
End Sub
```

Comment: would this create a database every time? and what are the advantages of using access?

Comment: You only need to create database once. Using a database avoids hundreds of spreadsheets in filesystem folders. You centralize, normalize, and efficient store all needed data.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Should I delete the database code after its run once?

Comment: All depends on how you deploy. The database may move or need to be recreated. Remember Access databases are file-level so resides in a directory and not a server. Also, if you rerun this macro you may need to drop the created table, `conn.Execute "DROP TABLE MyExcelTable"`.